# How to set javascript variable to null before pageload

Tags: javascript

There is some code I would like to set to NULL before a page has loaded possible turning this into a chrome extension or grease monkey script. Here is the code in question:

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
            document.onfocusin = onFocus;
            document.onfocusout = onBlur;
        } else {
            window.onload = window.onfocus = onFocus;
            window.onblur = onBlur;
        }
    }

    function onBlur() {
        var vidnowApp = document.getElementById("vidnow");
        if (vidnowApp && vidnowApp.onAppDeactivate) {
            vidnowApp.onAppDeactivate();
        }
    }

    function onFocus() {
        var vidnowApp = document.getElementById("vidnow");
        if (vidnowApp && vidnowApp.onAppActivate) {
            vidnowApp.onAppActivate();
        }
    }
```

What is the best solution to set onBlur to null so that onFocus is always set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it ASAP (as in, in a script tag in body), but, focus the element you want to on the document being ready.

Comment: i tried this but it didnt work. `if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
  document.onfocusout = null;
 } else {
  window.onblur = null;
 }`

Comment: Try the jquery $(document).ready(). Use jquery had I promise you'll have a lot more friends.